# blackberry playbook simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook

i have downloaded the VMWare iso for blackberry playbook simulator and it works well.
how can i upload to it my Android application (blackberry online test says that is compatible) on the simulator?

In my Eclipe i don't have the "Run as" Blackberry simulator...so i can't upload it as i do with all the android apps.

Even if i create a new app choosing Blackberry project i can't upload it and, as you can see is the default one.

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;

/**
 * This class extends the UiApplication class, providing a
 * graphical user interface.
 */
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
    /**
     * Entry point for application
     * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
        // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
        MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }


    /**
     * Creates a new MyApp object
     */
    public MyApp()
    {        
        // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
        pushScreen(new MyScreen());
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code you've listed is a BB7 (or lower version) Java app which won't run on Playbook.

To upload an AIR or C++ app written for Playbook (or its VMWare simulator) you use **blackberry-deploy.bat** coming with WebWorks SDK or with [the other RIM SDKs](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/devzone/):

```
blackberry-deploy.bat -installApp -password qaqa -device 192.168.1.128 -package my_app.bar"
```

I'm not sure about Android Java apps, maybe you can use the same batch file for them too?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you want to do ?
Playbook support Application created for Playbook not for Blackberry smartphones & it provide runtime environment for Android applications. 
So if you wish to create an app for Playbook You can choose Flash builder to develop in Adobe Air.
Or if you want to run your android application to playbook follow this to install blackberry plugin on your eclipse.

```
https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/install_plugin_prerequisites_1895476_11.html
```

Once you are ready with Blackberry  plugin , you need to verify your app for Blackberry Playbook(Follow this Link)

```
https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/Test_your_app_1985225_11.html
```